# react+django+rest_framework+jwt API refresh token sometimes response 401 Unauthorized

Tags: reactjs, django, jwt, refresh-token

My problem is most of the time the token refreshed ok. Sometimes when I refresh manually, the server responds 401. If I refreshed again, the server responds 200. Not sure why.

The django server side shows:

```
Unauthorized: /api/token/refresh/
[28/Jan/2024 16:44:04] "POST /api/token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 401 58
[28/Jan/2024 16:44:04] "GET /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 109
[28/Jan/2024 16:48:05] "POST /api/token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 531
[28/Jan/2024 16:52:06] "POST /api/token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 531
[28/Jan/2024 16:56:07] "POST /api/token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 531
[28/Jan/2024 17:00:08] "POST /api/token/refresh/ HTTP/1.1" 200 531
```

Frontend react code:

context.js

```
const refreshToken = async ()=>{
  let localToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authToken'))
  console.log(localToken)
  if (localToken){
    try{
      const res = await fetch(apiUrl + 'token/refresh/',{
          method: "POST", 
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            'refresh': localToken.refresh
          }),
        })
      if (!res.ok){
          // if(res.status === 401){
          //     handleLogout(localToken)
          // }
          throw Error
      }
      const data = await res.json()
      setToken(data)
      setUser(jwtDecode(data.access).username)
      if(isInit){
        setIsInit(false)
      }
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', JSON.stringify(data))
      
    }
    catch (err){
      console.log(err)
    }
  }
}
```

App.js

```
  useEffect(()=>{
if(!isLogin){
  if(isInit){
    refreshToken()
  
  }
  else{
    console.log('interval')
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
      refreshToken()
    },1000*60*4)

    
    return ()=> clearInterval(interval)
    
  }
}

 },[token])
```

backend

urls.py   I use the built-in `Tokenrefreshview.`

```
urlpatterns = [

path('', PostList.as_view(), name='listcreate'),
path('<int:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='detailcreate'),
path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
path('token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```